# ES6 Arrow Function unexpected token

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm getting this error

```
[11:55:38] Unexpected token => at test.js :
175 |    // }
176 |  })
177 |  var f = (req, res, next) => {
------------------------------------^
178 |    return res.json('test');
179 |  };
```

When running this specific code.

```
var f = (req, res, next) => {
  return res.json('test');
};

app.get('/test', f);
```

I'm playing around with ES6 and I can't find a solution for this error even though my route was working properly and returning 'test'.

What is the problem with this snippet?

```
'use strict';

module.exports.controller = function (app) {

  app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => {
    return res.json('test');
  });
}
```

Comment: Which version of NodeJS? Looks like Arrow function is not supported by it.

Comment: Also, How your application ran (returning `test`), when its having error "Unexpected token => at test.js"?

Comment: I'm using v6.2.0. I think this is the latest release.

Comment: @JagsSparrow I know it's weird that's why I'm here. I'm thinking it might be only the debugger. Because when I'm accessing it in the browser I can see the result

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I added the whole code. (I removed everything except for the updated code and still got the same error)

Comment: @JonathanLonowski `$ node -p 'process.versions'
{ http_parser: '2.7.0',
  node: '6.2.0',
  v8: '5.0.71.47',
  uv: '1.9.1',
  zlib: '1.2.8',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  icu: '57.1',
  modules: '48',
  openssl: '1.0.2h' }`

Comment: @kdlcruz-cloudemployee Since you mentioned the error may occur with a debugger, how are you debugging the code? Are you running `node debug {script}` or using another package or application?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I'm running it using nodemon from gulpfile. I thought at first it was the jslint but the error shows after the lint was done.

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace with the error?

Comment: @loganfsmyth nothing that just it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out where it came from, the error came from the `gulp-jscs`.
Updating `gulp-jscs` to *3.0.2* fixes the error.

Answer (score 0):

You can write

```
module.exports.controller = function (app) {
    app.get('/test', (req, res, next) => res.json('test'));
}
```

because [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Function_body) return **always** the result of the last expression **without** curly brackets.

Comment: You need braces for statements, and a `return`. You can leave off the braces if the body of the function is an expression.

Comment: @FizzyTea, it is in this case.

Comment: Yeah, the point is arrow functions don't return the result of the last statement. You need a `return` unless the body of the function is an expression.

Comment: @FizzyTea arrows are there for mostly inline operations like in Array methods or passing a calculated argument to a function. If you find yourself in need to use curly braces and return in an arrow then i suppose you best use proper function notation instead. Having said that at some cases i have to group the instructions with parens like. `a.reduce((p,c) => (c.stg == 42 && p.push(c.stg),p),[]);` so yes the last instruction gets returned in this case.

Comment: Yeah, the original wording was 'statement', and that's not a statement.

Comment: But the code the OP has is not incorrect, so it doesn't really solve the larger issue. *"result of the last expression"* gives the impression that there can be multiple expressions in a brace-less arrow function. However, there the body can actually only be a single expression.

Comment: the larger issue has a [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37404818/1447675). the rest is just an offer.